# Call mobile detection class method in ASP.NET app_code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, detection, app-code

## Summary

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 website and a mobile detection method inside a C# class file inside my app_code folder. I want to call this method which sets a cookie, then switch my master page file if it's a mobile device.

I'm using a method i got from the comment section down in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET

This just seemed simpler than using the 51degrees method of detection since i didn't really need a high level of detection, and i didn't want to send them to a different URL, but rather just flip to a different masterpage, and the NuGet package which makes a nice easy install doesn't work for ASP.NET 3.5.

The problem i'm at currently is with calling the method.

## Here's the Code

### External app_code class

```
public static class fooBar // test method
{
    public static bool ean()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static class HttpRequestExt
{
    #region Private Fields

    // These regular expressions retrieved from http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ "Open source mobile phone detection".
    private static Regex MobileBrowsers = new Regex(@"android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    private static Regex MobileApps = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    #endregion

    public const string ViewMobileSiteCookieName = "ViewMobile";

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the request emanated from a mobile-device client; 
    /// and stores the result in a cookie on the response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <param name="Response"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// 
    public static bool IsMobileClient(this System.Web.HttpRequest request, System.Web.HttpRequest Response)
    {
        bool isMobile = false;
        bool isCookieSet = false;
        var viewMobileCookie = request.Cookies[ViewMobileSiteCookieName];

        if (viewMobileCookie != null && bool.TryParse(viewMobileCookie.Value, out isMobile))
        {
            isCookieSet = true;
        }
        else if (request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            isMobile = true;
        }
        else if (request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"].IsNotEmpty())
        {
            isMobile = true;
        }
        else if
            (
                request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].IsNotEmpty()
                &&
                (
                    request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wap")
                    || request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wml+xml")
                )
            )
        {
            isMobile = true;
        }
        else if (request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].IsNotEmpty())
        {
            string userAgent = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            isMobile = ((MobileBrowsers.IsMatch(userAgent) || MobileApps.IsMatch(userAgent.Substring(0, 4))));
        }

        // Store the result as a cookie.
        if (!isCookieSet)
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(ViewMobileSiteCookieName, isMobile.ToString()));

        return isMobile;
    }

    public static bool IsNotEmpty(this string instance)
    {
        return instance != null && instance.Length > 0;
    }
}
```

### My call to it)

Right now im doing it on the page, but i figure i'll do this in global.asax on session start?

```
sectionTitle.InnerHtml = fooBar.ean().ToString(); // test works
sectionTitle.InnerHtml = HttpRequestExt.IsMobileClient.ToString(); // compile error
```

#### Compile Error:

> CS0119: 'SWIC.HttpRequestExt.IsMobileClient(System.Web.HttpRequest, System.Web.HttpRequest)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Do i have to somehow cast this to the current instance? Should i just be doing this differently all together?

Comment: In the long run, just using responsive design would be better than a mobile master page. Will you want to update that Regex every time something new comes out, as well as maintain two sets of code? What about pages that won't render correctly in the mobile master... do you need a different version of that page?

Comment: The problem i have with that is for instance; the IPhone 5 has a res like a desktop. So then wouldn't i have to start targeting specific screen resolutions? Also my other issue i see is, while all of my content basically the same(im hiding slideshows, ect), my master layout has different markup(JQuery Mobile, icons, pop-up menu, ect). I don't think id be able to it with just media queries, ASP would have to know whats going on to dynamically remove certain extraneous things in an attempt to minify. I could just hide them via css, but then asp still has to do all the computing in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a method like a property. Methods need parentheses:

```
HttpRequestExt.IsMobileClient().ToString()
                             ^^
```

You'll also have to call it on the current request, not just statically, as it is an extension method (which takes a parameter). E.g.:

```
sectionTitle.InnerHtml = Page.Request.IsMobileClient(Page.Response).ToString();
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, when i try this i just get this error instead:

CS1501: No overload for method 'IsMobileClient' takes '0' arguments

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper: That method is expecting a single parameter, an `HttpRequest`. Although I think there might be a mistake in the extension code: the second parameter should be an `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Ya, i was a little confused about the parameters. I've tried passing it some things already with no avail. Using intellisense i tried to see what my HttpRequest and Respense options where, but all i get are some comparison methods. I'm not sure how to access my current HttpRequest/Response objects.

Comment: I tried this: sectionTitle.InnerHtml = Page.Request.IsMobileClient(HttpContext.Current.Request, HttpContext.Current.Response).ToString();

and i get : CS1501: No overload for method 'IsMobileClient' takes '2' arguments

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper: `IsMobileClient()` is an [*extension* method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx); it extends the type of object specified as the first parameter (the one with `this` in front of it). Technically, it takes only one parameter when it's called (the second one).